# Should we use different usernames for each website, to achieve better anonymity?

Tags: password-management, anonymity, user-names

I have big problems trying to remember different usernames for each site. Chrome remembers only passwords, so I should install a password manager, however it's crazy you have to do that in order to do something so  basic as different username for each site.

If you have same username each site, you are easily googleable and all your accounts can be linked and thus de-anonymised.

It's clear one should use different password for each site. How about usernames, is password manager the best solution? Can chrome do it by itself?

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure about Chrome, but I have a feeling it was able to remember my username for most sites.

As for anonymity, it really depends on what you mean. Anonymity in the strictest meaning is actually a misnomer. To achieve anonymity, you could not select any username at all. Anonymity means not even two of your posts on the same site can be linked together. So you would not register at all.

Pseudonymity is when you have an identity for certain purpose, that can't be linked to your real identity. There are many "levels" of pseudonymity, you can have one pseudonym for everything on the internet, just not under your real name. You can have different pseudonym for each site or even each user you communicate with. The last one meaning if you send me two messages, I can tell both are from the same person, but if you send a message to my friend, we can't know, whether both were from the same person or not.

Whether you choose to be anonymous or pseoudonymous and at what "level" or type of pseudonymity depends entirely on what you are trying to achieve. Do you care that people can link the identities together? Are you worried you may leak your real identity or clues and you don't want that to "spread"? Do you want people to be able to recognize your username? It is up to you and your preference.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the common misconceptions wrt the term "anonymity".

Comment: I think I may accept this answer, however I'll let time pass since it's common practice. I like this answer and agree with it, and I'll learnt this new way to correctly think about anonymity. I think then the answer to the question in the title: "Should we use different usernames for each website, to achieve better anonymity?" is yes, but with the caveat that another more stuff can be done to achieve even more anonymity. I'm thinking now this question: how to be protected from common people, civilians, from seeing your public posts in the internet. I think different usernames would help a lot

Comment: @Santropedro In general, what you have here is an opsec question. They are infamously threat model-specific and sometimes a little subjective!

Comment: @Santropedro My point sort of was, that you actually may want to have the same username everywhere, as it has its own advantages. You may get more "respect" elsewhere by being well known and knowledgeable here on SE. Or for example a friend who knows your username can see easily whether you use some site without having to ask you. It depends on what you try to achieve.

Comment: @forest Ah ok, i didn't know "opsec" word. I should add as a tag then. Also, I have threats in my mind, and I avoided putting them on the question, in hopes that the question being 1 more general to be able to garner more attention 2 less words so people are willing to read it. I also asked the question general like this because i believed questions that are too specific only help me, while questions general help many people (and i win upvotes in the question! :) )